# Error when I try to install matplotlib on my Mac for Python

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, osx-leopard

I am trying to install 'matplotlib' on my mac using pip3 command however this is the message I am receiving. I am not sure how to fix it.

```
**Installing collected packages: matplotlib
    Running setup.py install for matplotlib ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/sc/wgsjhdm14ndgnb_h29xym4400000gn/T/pip-install-mnsalhc3/matplotlib/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/sc/wgsjhdm14ndgnb_h29xym4400000gn/T/pip-install-mnsalhc3/matplotlib/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/sc/wgsjhdm14ndgnb_h29xym4400000gn/T/pip-record-2nvm9f0y/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/matplotlib
         cwd: /private/var/folders/sc/wgsjhdm14ndgnb_h29xym4400000gn/T/pip-install-mnsalhc3/matplotlib/
    Complete output (624 lines):
    
    Edit setup.cfg to change the build options; suppress output with --quiet.
    
    BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
      matplotlib: yes [3.3.2]
          python: yes [3.9.0 (v3.9.0:9cf6752276, Oct  5 2020, 11:29:23)  [Clang 6.0
                      (clang-600.0.57)]]
        platform: yes [darwin]
     sample_data: yes [installing]
           tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]
          macosx: yes [installing]
    
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9
    copying lib/pylab.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/mpl_toolkits
    copying lib/mpl_toolkits/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/mpl_toolkits
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/matplotlib
 
    copying lib/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid
    copying lib/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/axes_size.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid
    copying lib/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/angle_helper.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid
    copying lib/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/grid_helper_curvelinear.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-**
```

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you were more specific. Are you trying to install through the command line? If so, what command are you running specifically?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error while installing matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359383/error-while-installing-matplotlib)

Comment: You seem to have removed the useful parts; it says there would be 624 lines of output but you only provide the success part of the story. Anyway, the problem is that `matplotlib` is not yet compatible with Python 3.9.

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks for the reply! i managed to install matplotlib :)